# Will a destructor unit test be optimised away?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, destructor, compiler-optimization

I have created an `Initializer` class for my project which performs initialization in it's constructor and deinitialization in its destructor. The user of my project creates an `Initializer` object on the stack once at the start of his program, ensuring that deinitialization takes place when it goes out of scope (e.g. at program termination):

```
Class Initialiser
{
   Initialiser()
   {
      // Acquire resources
   }
   ~Initialiser()
   {
      // Free resources
   }
}
```

I want to create a unit test to ensure that the deinitialization takes place correctly e.g.:

```
bool verifyDeinitialization()
{
   // Code to check that no resources are allocated
   // Return true if none allocated, false otherwise
}

// Syntax below is for UnitTest++:

TEST(Initializer_Destructor_DeinitializationWorks)
{
   {
      Initializer init; // Will this be optimized away?
   } // init goes out of scope, destructor called
   CHECK(verifyDeinitialization())
}
```

My question is - if the destructor completely reverses the effects of the constructor by freeing all the resources it acquired, will the compiler detect that nothing observable has happened, and optimise away the `init` object? I'm concerned that my unit test could then provide a false negative (pass the test when it potentially could have been a fail), as correct deinitialization is equivalent to initialization never having taken place in the first place (in both cases, there are no resources which have been acquired).

Comment: While the compiler is allowed to do so, I highly doubt any modern compiler will actually do such an "optimization".  That's because code where constructors and destructors completely cancel out is rare to non-existant in real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is ***allowed to do so***. Whether it definitely will is something that cannot be answered convincingly, this is because compiler optimizations are not guaranteed by the standard.

However, You can simply tweak your code to set up some flag if initialization indeed happens & check this flag in your `verifyDeinitialization()` function to detect whether initialization actually happened and was followed by successful deinitialization or there was no initialization in the first place. In short you can use a simple flag to distinguish the two scenarios.

Comment: Would I not then face the same issue with the flag? The compiler sees that the only observable effect of the `init` object is that the flag is set to true, and simply sets it to true without creating `init`?

Comment: @JBentley: AFAIU, Either the object will not be created & hence not destroyed or there will be a call to constructor followed by one to destructor. It cannot be anything other than that. If you are really concerned then you should embed some code which produces an observable behavior or side effect in this code to make sure the compiler does not optimize anything.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking, could I simply do a `std::cout << &init` in my unit test? Would that force the compiler to create the object since I'm sending it's address to cout?

Comment: @JBentley: Do make sure you use `std::endl` to flush the output buffer :)

Comment: I very much *doubt* that any compiler would completely elide the construction of an object like that, unless the object's constructor and destructor provably had no side-effects. But if there exists a function like `verifyDeinitialization()` that can detect if the "deinitialization" succeeded, then I assert that at least the destructor **must**, *necessarily*, have observable side-effects.